# Dotenv behaves differently in different environments (not parsing out quotes)

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I have a .env.local file that looks like this:

```
SOME_URL="localhost:3000"
```

My javascript file looks like this:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: '.env.local' });

const host = process.env.SOME_URL;

console.log('host', host);
```

When I run this script locally, I get the correct expected output:

```
host localhost:3000
```

But when I containerize this script and run it with Docker, I get the following output:

```
host "localhost:3000"
```

In the container version, the quote marks are being included as part of the string.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a misunderstanding on my part, and not a problem with `dotenv`. I was only using `dotenv` in the development environment, and in the Docker environment, environment variables were being specified by an `enf_file` in `docker-compose`. `docker-compose` parses env files differently than `dotenv` does, and includes surrounding quotes in the values.